# How can I send serial commands to a CSZ 570i temperature chamber in python?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm trying to send serial commands to a test chamber in our lab in order to set the temperature from our connected PC. Let's say for example I want to send the command "01 06 00 3C 00 C8 48 50", I've attempted to do so using functions such as the following:

```
def set_temp_hex_command(command):
    ser = serial.Serial('COM9', 9600, timeout=5)
    bytes_command = bytes.fromhex(command)
    ser.write(bytes_command)
    response = ser.read(10)  
    print("Response:", response)
    ser.close()

def set_temp_hex_command(command):
    ser = serial.Serial('COM9', 9600, timeout=1)
    print("Sent: ", command.encode())
    ser.write(command.encode())
    response = ser.read(10)  
    print("Response:", response)
    ser.close()
```

As well as a bunch of different formattings and other minor changes. Yet the machine is not registering the commands, nor is it sending a return response. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Here is a link to the documentation for the chamber https://www.cszindustrial.com/portals/1/pdf/EZT_570i_User_Communication_Reference_Manual_revA.pdf

Comment: Do you know how far your program gets at all? Does the connection (ser = etc.etc.) even succeed? Also, what is command? Is it a string? Have you tried to see if the bytes_command variable has a value right after running the fromhex?

Comment: It seems to connect fine, it's just that the response is always given as "Response: b''", and the chamber itself isn't actually changing temperature or anything as it would if the command was successfully written. I haven't tried printing the bytes_command, I'll have to try that when I get the chance.

Comment: Unrelated but both you methods have the same signature. Might want to change that. In one you use command.encode and the other uses bytes.fromhex to form the payload. These might give different results. Have you tried with both of them?